# Why the SouthWest's point.x is not 0 on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

this is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed', function () {
            var left_bottom=map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest())
            console.log(left_bottom)
        });
```

I think the result may be this:

(0,some number),

but the result is:

(232.31212222222223, 155.07739681860028)

so why the SouthWest's point.x is not 0?

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, and I might sound like an ass when I say this, but, what *is* 0?

Comment: Could be a coordinate plane similar to Flash where the 0, 0 origin is in the north west corner.

Answer (score 0):

`.getProjection` is returning the mercator projection, it's a coordinate system where 0,0 is in the top left of a cylindrical representation of a map (like Google uses) at the north pole and international date line, and icreases as you head east/south.  The upper bound is 256.